# Referenced before assignment - tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm not sure why I get an error message when I click on get button. I've moved things around and I still get this error message.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1536, in __call__
     return self.func(*args)
  File "address.py", line 5, in getName
     first_name = first_name.get()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'first_name' referenced before assignment
```

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def getName(event):
    first_name = first_name.get()
    fieldEntry.insert(0, first_name)

root = Tk()
root.title('Address Book')
Label(root, text='First Name').grid(row=0, sticky=W, padx=4)
first_name = Entry(root).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

Label(root, text='Last Name').grid(row=1, sticky=W, padx=4)
last_name = Entry(root).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

#Button(root, text='Submit').grid(row=3)

getNameButton = Button(root, text='Get')
getNameButton.bind('<Button-1>', getName)
getNameButton.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E)


fieldEntry = Entry(root)
fieldEntry.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=E)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try renaming the variable `first_name` inside `getName` to something else, like `name`. I think it just has a conflict with the first_name from `Entry`

Comment: Or eliminate the local by replacing the two lines with `fieldEntry.insert(0, first_name.get())`

Answer (score 2):

You've got two problems.  When you write:

```
first_name = first_name.get()
```

Python sees `first_name` on the left hand side of an assignment and it assumes that `fist_name` is a local variable.  Then when it is run, when it looks up `first_name` (on the right hand side), it only looks on the function's locals.  Since the local `first_name` hasn't yet been populated in the *local* namespace, it raises an `UnboundLocalError`.  I'd recommend changing the name of the global:

```
first_name_entry = Entry(root)
first_name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)
```

Notice that to solve the second problem, I split the entry creation from gridding it.  The reason is because `Widget.grid` returns `None` which means that (in your handling code), `first_name` was previously `None` instead of being the entry that you were expecting it to be.

---

Here's a full script that works on my computer:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def getName(event):
    first_name = first_name_entry.get()
    fieldEntry.insert(0, first_name)

root = Tk()
root.title('Address Book')
Label(root, text='First Name').grid(row=0, sticky=W, padx=4)
first_name_entry = Entry(root)
first_name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

Label(root, text='Last Name').grid(row=1, sticky=W, padx=4)
last_name = Entry(root).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

#Button(root, text='Submit').grid(row=3)

getNameButton = Button(root, text='Get')
getNameButton.bind('<Button-1>', getName)
getNameButton.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E)


fieldEntry = Entry(root)
fieldEntry.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=E)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I made the changes you recommended but i still get the same error message.

Comment: @GabrielMoreno -- I just tried my changes on your script and it works for me.  I've posted the full thing in case there's something that you're missing from my description...

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing `first_name`, in a function before it's been defined later on in the program. You have to define `first_name` before the `getName()` function. You could also put the `getName()` function after you define `first_name`.